# Display symbolic links in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently switched from atom to VS Code, and there's one key feature that I can't seem to find.

Is it possible to display a symbolic link in the Visual Studio Code file explorer?

Comment: To future googlers, this feature has shipped. If you can't see a symlinked file, you have made the symlink incorrectly (as happened in my case)

Comment: @JonMcClung It doesn't seem to work. at least for me (cygwin and vscode's terminal see the links, but Vscode explorer and pylint/python not)

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: related, but my symlinks in the remote folder don't apper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76725830/how-to-make-explorer-in-remote-shh-extension-in-visual-studio-code-vscode-do

Comment: @JonMcClung I'm aware this is a stretch 5 years later, but do you recall what you meant by "made the symlink incorrectly", and what _was_ the correct way?

Answer (score 6):

The February 2018 update for VSCode includes support for symbolic links.

The links appear as below:

[image]

For further info check this page:
[VSCode February 2018 update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_21)

Comment: It seems not to work for me. Links are correctly created/seen on the terminal and on Cygwin. VScode shows .lnk files and python can't read them. Any idea why? (vscode is the newest release)

Comment: This is still not working (December 2019): "The file is not displayed in the editor. It is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding."

Comment: @maugch could you fix it? I am also facing the same issue. The linked folder is visible in the Explorer but Python code is not able to access it. Debug throws "Failed to open ..." error.

Comment: @haripkannan I had everything done on Linux and it worked, once I open the solution in Windows I see just a lnk file. I think I created the links using windows as admin and then I pulled again.

Comment: In windows open a command line as Admin, and use the following command: `mklink Link Target`. This will create a (soft) symbolic link.
Example: `mklink C:\Development\cic.evaluate.antlr\JavaScript\src\Tests\ClarionExprParser.Debugger.txt C:\Development\cic.evaluate.antlr\Tests\ClarionExprParser_Debugger.txt`

Comment: related, but my symlinks in the remote folder don't apper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76725830/how-to-make-explorer-in-remote-shh-extension-in-visual-studio-code-vscode-do

Answer (score 2):

There was an [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11539) to provide support for this which was resolved in February 2018 and included in the March 2018 release.

Comment: related, but my symlinks in the remote folder don't apper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76725830/how-to-make-explorer-in-remote-shh-extension-in-visual-studio-code-vscode-do

Answer (score 1):

Not only VSCode displays symlinks, but with [VSCode 1.43 (Q1 2020)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/7415295786638654d08e2a88c41e737b803edb89/release-notes/v1_43.md#notable-fixes), it will also display **dangling symlinks**.

See [issue 90075](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90075):

> - create symbolic links (either file or folder) and delete the target.
> - Make sure the links still show up in the file explorer with their link decoration on the right hand side.
>
> You can delete them, or open them and type to create them.

[image: Screenshot 2020-02-05 at 16 12 10 -- https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/900690/73854135-49af2080-4832-11ea-8c85-920280d36339.png]