# How to make explorer in remote - shh extension in Visual Studio Code (VsCode) does show symlinks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

Is it possible to display a symbolic link in the Visual Studio Code file explorer when using Visual Studio Mode (VsCode)?

Currently I can login to the server and open the right forlder but cannot see the symlinks. This is needed because the data folder is different because the server uses a different file system for the data which can be huge compared to the local disk space for simple github repos/code/text.

An alternative solution could be to add a single folder to the data. I'm fine with that. Or in reverse add the folder where all the github repos/code is.

related issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071131/display-symbolic-links-in-visual-studio-code'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071131/display-symbolic-links-in-visual-studio-code%27)

the issue is because when vscode connects to the server it loses some permission but soln is not outlined here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3576 it doesn't happen when I ssh in a seperate terminal outside of vscode

cross: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8731

[image]

Comment: you might have luck with this google search query or modifications to it: `site:github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues symlink explorer`

Comment: @starball even better would be if I can add only the symlinks I want to the explorer view.

Comment: the issue is because when vscode connects to the server it loses some permission but soln is not outlined here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3576 it doesn't happen when I ssh in a seperate terminal outside of vscode

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue seems to be particular to my cluster that is set up in a ridiculous fashion. There is a odd token kerberos thing that they over manage (mentioned here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/724685/how-does-one-authenticate-with-a-command-that-requires-your-password-in-linux) anyway once I run `reauth` it works. So make sure your permissions are right, for me it was through by getting the token again. The symlinks refreshed by themselvers.

[image]